# At least one valid parameter is needed in order to initialize an AutoNumeric object

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I am using AutoNumeric library in my Vue js V2 application, but I always get this error in console

**Error in mounted hook: "Error: At least one valid parameter is needed in order to initialize an AutoNumeric object"**

**At least one valid parameter is needed in order to initialize an AutoNumeric object**

I'm using AutoNumeric in this way:

I did npm install autonumeric --save

```
<p id="my-input" class="my-input" contenteditable="true">12</p>

<script>
import AutoNumeric from 'autonumeric';
export default {
  mounted() {
    new AutoNumeric(document.querySelector('.my-input'), AutoNumeric.getPredefinedOptions().integerPos);
  }
}
</script>
```

Comment: Are you using vue2 or vue3?

Answer (score 0):

Note: In order to minimize the size of the vue-autoNumeric component, the AutoNumeric library dependency is not bundled with it.

https://github.com/autoNumeric/vue-autoNumeric